# how to open a new workbook with new application in excel2016

Tags: excel, windows

when I was using Excel2007,I can open a new excel application with double click Excel.exe.However,when I upgrade to version 2016,it doesn't work.What ever I try, I can't open a new workbook in a new application except code.How could I open a new application just through mouse click or any settings ,but not code like vba?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You press **ALT key** and **HOLD IT**
2. click on the workbook you want to open (or just the Excel icon)
3. Keep holding down Alt key **few seconds** until a dialog box opens
4. "**Do you want to start a new instance of Excel?**" click  on **yes**.
5. Done

This is very handy even if you want two VBA windows at the same time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I've tried to do the actions you've told me.
# But, unfortunately, when I holding the ALT key down and click on the workbook.
There was nothing happend,just like click without ALT key down.
#If I press the ALT key,then double click the workbook, I got in the property dialog normally.

Comment: You might not have an Excel Shortcut in the Taskbar. Do the above methode on an Excel icon in the Windows Start menue instead. (Or add an Excel Icon to your taskbar and try again)

Comment: Excetied,I make it, that's what I need!